# Грамматика для оператора if

Tags: c++

Язык С++.
Задача состоит в том, что бы создать автомат Мура. Нужно написать грамматику для оператора if.

Условие задачи:

Операторы условного перехода (if) на языке C++ без вложенностей с произвольным условием (любой набор логических операций и выражений отношения).

Насколько я понял это так: **if(a>b || b>a && и так далее)**

Что хочу вообще: интересные варианты условия для **if**. Хотелось бы в грамматике больше случаев учесть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `if ((a<b)+(b<c)*3>d<f+++ ++f&a||r?d:a&2[&""[b]]^c=!**d) ...`

Comment: @Discord а вот это уже интересно)

Comment: Вы бы вместо фото почёрканного листочка не поленились набить текст и отформатировать. И объяснить, что такое «автомат Мура».

Comment: @VladD На счет автомата Мура - википедия, а вот листочек - черновик.Я так привык

Comment: Понятно. Ответ в гугле, мы так привыкли.

Comment: @VladD Обиделись что ли? Просьба то у меня в другом. Варианты условия для if. Если вы знаете какие то, напишите пожалуйста

Comment: @Александр: Что вы, я не обиделся. Просто если вам, человеку, наиболее заинтересованному в ответе на вопрос, лень объяснить, что такое «автомат Мура», то уж отвечающим типа меня тоже лень читать википедию.

Comment: [Что-то такое?](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/)  (ищется по запросу `c++ expression grammar`, внутри содержит в т.ч. грамматику выражений, которые м.б. в `if`) Ну, а конечный автомат Мура (таблицы переходов его состояний) уж как-нибудь сами нарисуйте.

Comment: @Александр Вы лучше подумайте на чем вам остановится, ибо внутри if можно написать любой код на языке C который возвращает какой либо результат. Т.е. что бы учесть полностью все варианты которые вам напишут, вам придется описать грамматику практически всего C :)

Answer (score 4):

Лучше б сам подумал, а то я тебе тут напишу...

http://ideone.com/I7sxiw

```
if ([](){}(), 7)
```

Comment: Почему не `42`? ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а [как у @VladD](/questions/465586/Можно-ли-как-то-вывести-квадрат-из-букв-s-другим-способом-используя-while/465605#comment514050_465605) не получится))